# GLKTextureLoader is only able to load one texture

Tags: ios, objective-c, opengl-es, glkit, glktextureloader

I am having an issue loading in textures through a load texture method.

```
+(Texture*) loadTexture: (NSString*) name path: (NSString*) path{
    CGImageRef imageReference = [[UIImage imageNamed:path] CGImage];

    GLKTextureInfo* textureInfo = [GLKTextureLoader textureWithCGImage:imageReference options:nil error:NULL];

    Texture* texture = [[Texture alloc] init:textureInfo];

    NSLog(@"width: %i height: %i data: %p", [texture Width], [texture Height], [texture getTextureInfo]);

    if(!Textures) Textures = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    [Textures setObject:texture forKey:name];
    NSLog(@"adding key %@ to dictionary with pointer %p", name, Textures);
    NSLog( @"%@", Textures );

    return texture;
}
```

The first time I call the load texture method all is well, but any subsequent calls to load texture the textureInfo fails to be initialized and the NSLog shows "width: 0 height: 0 data: 0x0"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out why it wasn't working and here is a link to the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/13948618/7914426